# Flex/AS3 : Automatically instantiate package classes in an array (plugin classes)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This is my first time here, but I already found some good answers here, so I'd like to thank everyone.

I'm developping a small Flex application and I want to instantiate every class from a package into an array, so I can parse it afterwards. To clarify, I'm trying to ease a plugin management system for my application, with the old canProcess/doProcess routine : 
My plugins are all in ONE package, including an abstract plugin class. First, I create one instance of every classes in this package (that's where I need help) and put them in an array. Then, whenever I need a plugin for an item, I parse every plugin class in my array with the canProcess method (the item is the parameter). If one plugin says yes, then I send the item to the doProcess method and stop parsing the array.

I know I could implement by hand every class in my package, but I'd prefer not bothering to do it.

Has anyone an idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

AS3 reflection doesn't allow you to list all classes in a package. You will have to write the class names to an (xml) file at the server, load it and then use [getDefinitionByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()) to get `Class` objects from those strings and then instantiate them.

Consider the sample xml file:

```
<root package="boris.ratak">
  <className>Plugin1</className>
  <className>Plugin2</className>
  <className>Plugin3</className>
</root>
```

load it with [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) and parse it like:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

var pack:String = String(xml.@package) + ".";
for each(var cl:String in xml.className)
{
   var name:String = pack + String(cl.text());
   var Type:Class = getDefinitionByName(name) as Class;
   pluginArray.push(new Type());
}
```